# How to implement Captcha in zk ce

Tags: java, zk

I'm new to the zkoss framework. I tried to implement `captcha` but there is no `captcha` support in zk-ce. Does anyone know how to implement  captcha support for zk-ce.

Thanks for any help and reference links

Thanks
Clark

Answer (score 0):

I had found a document talking about captcha in zul might help:
[Small Talks/2010/January/Bwcaptcha: Another Implementation of Captcha](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small%20Talks/2010/January/Bwcaptcha:%20Another%20Implementation%20of%20Captcha)